# Timer using a time function in C

Tags: c, time, timer

I want to print a line and then get it erased after ten seconds.
So I thought that I should write a timer as a preliminary programme and with erasure I could deal later using whatever I find on the internet (using `\r` for example).
And so I want to print "I love nachos" and ten seconds later "I hate nachos".
However, even though `printf("I love nachos")` is written before any conditions, the programme prints both strings after ten seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("I love nachos");
  time_t now = time(NULL);
  while (1)
  {
  time_t future = time(NULL);
    if ((future-now)==10)
      {
       break;
      }
  }
  printf("I hate nachos");
  return 0;
}
```

I asked my friend to tackle the problem and he wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Start\n");

    time_t t0 = time(NULL);

    while ( (difftime(time(NULL), t0)) <= 10.0 )
    {}

    printf("End");

    return 0;
}
```

However, in that case the programme only works with `\n` in `printf("Start\n")`.
If I remove `\n` I get the same result as per my initial code and I obviously don't want `\n` there, because I wouldn't be able to erase the line with `\r`

Comment: Instead of busy waiting in a loop I suggest to use a function like `sleep`/`nanosleep` (POSIX) or `Sleep` (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` output to `stdout` is by default line buffered. That means nothing is actually sent out until either the internal buffer is full *or* a newline is added *or* the FILE is closed (as happens implicitly when the program exits)

So either add a newline or use `fflush` to force the buffer to be transmitted immediately to the output.